# I want to allow the use of a data-flw attribute in links in comments

Tags: filters, comments, links, customization, wp-kses

I have come up with two ways I thought this should work and I'm having no joy with either.

First I tried hooking into the preprocess_comment filter.

```
// Set allowed html in comments.
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'csm_filter_allowed_comment_html' );

function csm_filter_allowed_comment_html( $comment ) {

    global $allowedtags;

    $allowedtags['a'] = array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array(),
        'rel' => array(),
        'data-flw' => array(),
    );
    return $comment;
}
```

But this did not allow me to use data-flw="true" in my comment anchors.

Then I thought, maybe I needed to do it earlier and bigger, so I tried just adding the filter to the { init }, figuring that the array would be altered already when a comment came along.

```
// Set allowed html in comments.
add_filter( 'init', 'csm_filter_allowed_comment_html' );

function csm_filter_allowed_comment_html() {

    global $allowedtags;

    $allowedtags['a'] = array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array(),
        'rel' => array(),
        'data-flw' => array(),
    );
}
```

Still nothing. I've read through the kses.php and I've searched for examples, most of the few I've found suggest my first attempt should work. I'm at a loss for where I've gone wrong here.